# How to prove existence of a diffeomorphism (Normal immersion theorem)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Assume $  \mathbb{R}^{n}\supseteq\mathcal{U}\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}^{m} $ is a $C^r$ function where $m\leq n$. Assume that $ \text{rank}\left[f'|_{p}\right]=m $ for some $p\in \mathcal{U}$. Porve that there exists a diffeomorphism $\psi$ such that $ f\circ\psi\left(x_{1},...,x_{n}\right)=f\left(p\right)+\left(x_{1},...,x_{m}\right) $.

**My thoughts:**

I want to define the following map:

$ \psi\left(x_{1},...,x_{n}\right)=\left(f_{1}\left(\underline{x}\right)-f_{1}\left(p\right),...,f_{m}\left(\underline{x}\right)-f_{m}\left(p\right),x_{m+1},...,x_{n}\right) $

Jacobian matrix is given by:

$$ \psi'=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} & \cdots &  & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{m}} & \cdots &  & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}}\\
\vdots & \ddots &  & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}} & \cdots &  & \frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{m}} & \cdots &  & \frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}\\
0 & \cdots &  & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
 &  &  &  &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$

(We know that the rank of $f'$ is $m$ in $p$ and therefor we know that the rank is $m$ in an open set around $p$, we can assume without loss of generality that this open set is $\mathcal{U} $ and otherwise we'll just look at a smaller set contained in $\mathcal{U} $).

Now, if I could prove that $\psi $ is a diffeomorphism then I'd get the existance of an inverse of $\psi$, and since

$ \pi\circ\psi\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)-f\left(p\right) $

Composing over $\psi^{-1}$ in both sides yields:

$$ \pi\circ\psi\circ\psi^{-1}=\left(f-f\left(p\right)\right)\circ\left(\psi^{-1}\right) $$

$$ \pi=f\circ\psi^{-1}\left(x\right)-f\left(p\right) $$

$$ \pi+f\left(p\right)=f\circ\psi^{-1} $$

Which is what I want.

I'd really appreciate some help about how to formalize this idea. How do I prove that this $\psi $ really is a diffeomorphism? (Basically I just need to show that this matrix is non-singular and than I can use the inverse function theorem).

Also, if there are more important details that I need to mention, I'd be happy to hear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know the rank of $f'$ is $m$, so *some* $m\times m$ submatrix is nonsingular.  Which one are you assuming it is?

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess I can assume its the submatrix $ \left[\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\right]_{1\leq i,j\leq m} $, up to changing the order of the variables.

Comment: Aha. So after you assert that, then you will have the nonsingular derivative matrix you need, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. Do you agree with the idea as it is written? for example, I actually defined the map $ \psi\left(x_{1},...,x_{n}\right)=\left(f_{1}\left(\underline{x}\right)-f_{1}\left(p\right),...,f_{m}\left(\underline{x}\right)-f_{m}\left(p\right),x_{m+1},...,x_{n}\right)$ in order to get the specific form $f(x)=f(p)+(x_1,...,x_m)$. What prevents me from defining $ \psi\left(x_{1},...,x_{n}\right)=\left(f_{1}\left(\underline{x}\right),...,f_{m}\left(\underline{x}\right),x_{m+1},...,x_{n}\right)$ and reach the form $f(x)=(x_1,...,x_m)$ although $f(p) \neq 0$ ?

Comment: @TedShifrin I feel like there's still missing important details